# I'm making Programs that open and close Excel files sequentially in sequence

Tags: python, excel, anaconda

I am trying to create a program that references data from many Excel files.
So this program should turn the Excel file on and off multiple times.

Initially it was made using

```
win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application").Workbooks.Open("fileaddress")
```

and

```
close()
```

but, error

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

was occurred.
So I used the 'with' statement.

```
with excel.Workbooks.Open("file_address"+"file_name") as c_wb:
```

Then an error occurred after the file was turned on.

```
AttributeError: __enter__
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Do you have a variable called `close` somewhere in your script?

Comment: I used 'Workbooks.Open()' and 'close()' in 'for' statement, and 'close()' is in last of 'for' statement.

Comment: Did you try `Workbooks.close()`?

Comment: I used `import win32com.client as win32` and `excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")` so actually `c_wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("address")`.

Comment: So I did `c_wb.close()`, And after seeing your comment, I did `c_wb.Workbooks.close()`. but, occurred error

Comment: `~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    525 
    526                 # no where else to look.
--> 527                 raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
    528 
    529         def __setattr__(self, attr, value):

AttributeError: Open.Workbooks
`

Comment: oh! I solved! 
I succeeded by using `Close()` instead of `close()`.

Comment: Great! You can write that as the answer down below!

Comment: oh, I can't do English well, and beginner of stack overflow. How can I write it?

Comment: Just write what you did in the box below here

Comment: Questions resulting from a typo are off topic and will eventually get deleted by the system. Deleting the question is the better thing to do, not self-answer @darthbith